# PDF of Powerpoint slides missing images

Tags: image, pdf, powerpoint

I'm working with Powerpoint 2010 on Windows 7.

I'm trying to convert the powerpoint (a research poster) to pdf. There are lots of images, most of which come through the pdf conversion fine, except some loss of quality. One of my images is a plot I first made in Mathematica which has many lines, so many colors. I inserted it into the powerpoint as an eps, and it worked fine. But in the pdf the axis labels are there but none of the actual plot. The other Mathematica plots that only have one line, so one color, turn out okay.

I've tried the built-in Save As pdf, "create pdf" from Adobe as well as online converters and they all have the same problem.

Any idea how to get the complete plots into the pdf?

Comment: In every version of Office, MS works out a new and bizarrely creative way to mis-handle EPS. If possible, free yourself from the cycle of inevitable despair by using some other format to bring graphics into PPT ... WMF/EMF or even PNGs.  Or if the graphics come into PPT looking OK, you can rightclick and save them out as WMF/EMF and re-insert them; that might give you something that prints.  Or it may be as simple as ungrouping the graphic and thickening the plot lines.